# On approximating problems in $\#P$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, approximation-algorithms, counting-complexity, derandomization, polynomial-hierarchy

We know that for every counting problem $\#A$ in $\#P$, there is a probabilistic algorithm
$\mathcal C$ that on input $x$, computes with high probability a value $v$ such that $$(1 − ε)\#A(x) ≤ v ≤ (1 + ε)\#A(x)$$
in time polynomial in $|x|$ and within $\frac1ε$ multiplicative factor, using an oracle for $NP$.

That is $\#P$ can be approximated in $BPP^{NP}$.

> What is the best derandomization result for this that is known?